# How to get File from DocumentFile in android version 29+ for File Manager App?

Tags: android, file, android-11, storage-access-framework, documentfile

I am developing File Manager, I have one issue in android version 30, when I get listFile() of OTG path its not return file, the only way to get all files is from DocumentFile, but now I want to get file as File from that DocumentFile how do I get, plz support me.

Comment: `when I get listFile() of OTG path` listFile()? Dont know that function. What is full path you use? Please post your code.

Comment: Be serious: if you want to make a file manager app then use DocumentFile all the way. No need for using the File class. DocumentFile is slow. So better use DocumentsContract as it is twenty times faster.

Answer (score 0):

You don't.  There's no promise that there is an actual File anywhere, it could be backed by a content provider calculating it at runtime, or reading it from a db.  Since a File can only represent a file on disk, there's no way to convert from a DocumentFile to a File.

Comment: I think that the only things that are on an OTG drive are files.

Comment: @blackapps Doesn't matter-  DocumentFile has no way to convert to a File because there's no promise its backed by a File.  The idea is you use a DocumentFile as is and don't need to know (or have access to) how its actually stored.

Answer (score 0):

USB OTG drives are often not mentioned any more in getExternalFilesDirs().

So you have no path.

Only with SAF ACTION_GET_DOCUMENT_TREE you can get an uri to the drive or folders on the drive.

Now its pretty easy to convert such an uri to a flie system path.(Look at all kinds of getRealFileForUri() implementations).

But even if you manage to get a path it is not usable.